# Angular and Microsoft Analysis Services

Tags: angular, ssas, dashboard

I have SQL Server databases and an Analysis Services layer to access these databases. I initially used it with Power BI to build a dashboard. But the dashboard doesn't look so nice specially on an iPad and it is a little slow. So I would like to switch to Angular for front end. But I do not know how to do the backend using the technologies that I already have. So what's the easiest way (free with no licence needed) to connect to the analysis services layer to fetch data and display it on angular visuals and charts?

Answer (score 0):

One of the contributor has come up with the solution (Work-in-progress) to integrate Analysis Services with Angular and can be found in the [Link](https://github.com/testpossessed/angular-olap)

This works by accessing Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) OLAP Cube via HTTP using XML/A and MDX queries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From a .NET Framework web service to you can send queries to Analysis Services using ADOMD.NET.  You can host the web service on Windows or on Azure App Service.  Here's a [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-analysis-services-http-sample) for Azure Analysis Services, but it would be the same.

Or you can configure a [SQL Server Linked Server for Analysis Services](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/218592/how-to-perform-a-sql-server-distributed-query-with-olap-server), and query that instead.